# Palindrome testing function

Tags: c++, math, numbers, palindrome

This function seems to be working for numbers with an odd number of digits but not for every number with an even number of digits (e.g. it returns true for 2662 but not for 906609).  I've been trying to figure it out for the last 20-30 minutes but I haven't found out why.

```
#include <math.h>

int digits(int n)
{
    return log10(n)+1;
}

bool ispalindrome(int n)
{
    int c=digits(n);
        for(int i=0; i<c/2; i++){
            int a=pow(10,i),b=pow(10,c-i-1);
            if(  int(n/a) %10 != int(n/b) %10 ) return false;
        }
        return true;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(int, char**argv)
{
    while (*++argv)
        std::cout << *argv
                  << (ispalindrome(std::atoi(*argv)) ? " is a palindrome." : " is not a palindrome.")
                  << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Pardon the obvious, but rather than performing digit by digit comparison as you would for string palindrome determination, wouldn't it be easier to just build a second number manufactured from the reverse digits of the input parameter and compare the that result with the original value?

Comment: What library did you use ? #include <math.h> ? No warnings when compiling ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://cpp.sh/9kt4

Comment: If this is repeatable on your machine it sounds like an excellent time to break out the debugger and go for a walk through the code. Off topic: `pow` can be brutally expensive and will likely kill this implementation if there are any performance constraints.

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't think about that, great idea, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce, but I think it'll be easier to compare int as a string == reversedString:

```
bool isPalindrome(const int& n)
{
   std::stringstream ssN;
   ssN << n;
   auto numberAsString = ssN.str();
   auto reversed = numberAsString;
   std::reverse(numberAsString.begin(), numberAsString.end());
   return numberAsString == reversed;
}
```

Please, check the code: [main.cpp](http://pastebin.com/84ApqR6T)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your results - I get the expected answer for both your test cases.

BTW, you can avoid the need for `<math.h>` by simply reversing the digits and then comparing with the original:

```
bool ispalindrome(int n)
{
    int a = 0;

    for (int r = n;  r;  r /= 10)
        a = a*10 + r%10;

    return a == n;
}
```